# Can't make OpenDialog window open in InitialDir

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5, openfiledialog

I'm having a problem getting my OpenDialog window to start in the appointed initialdir. 
What I currently have is tihs

```
procedure TForm1.fileMenuLoadClick(Sender: TObject);
begin     
SetCurrentDir(StartDir);
      SetCurrentDir('Cases');
      OpenDialog.Filename := '';
      OpenDialog.InitialDir := GetCurrentDir;
      OpenDialog.Filter := 'Sparfiler (.dat)|*.dat';
      // -------------------------------
      if OpenDialog.Execute then
      begin
        GeometryClear;
        DerobModel.Filename := OpenDialog.Filename;
        DerobModel.Open;
        pressed := True;
        SetCurrentDir('../');
        DerobModel.HouseProperties.StringValue['CaseDir'] := GetCurrentDir;
        DerobModel.HouseProperties.StringValue['StartDir'] := StartDir;
        SetCurrentDir(StartDir);
        UpdateGeometryPanel;
        mainUpdateComboBox;
        UpdatePropertiesPanel;
        UpdateEnergyPanel;
        UpdateAbsorption;
        UpdateClimatePanel;
        UpdateClimate;
        mainHide;
        Geometry.IsSelected := True;
        GeometryPanel.Visible := True;
        TreeView1.Enabled := True;
        TreeView1.HitTest := True;
        DerobModel.HouseProperties.BoolValue['GlazeChange'] := False;
      end;
```

When running this code it keeps opening the folder of the last file I've opened. I read that the solution is to clear the FileName property of OpenDialog but it doesn't work. However the funny thing is that it is working with this code which is from a previous version of my app.

```
procedure TForm1.fileMenuLoadClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SetCurrentDir(StartDir);
  SetCurrentDir('Cases');
  OpenDialog.Filename := '';
  OpenDialog.InitialDir := GetCurrentDir;
  OpenDialog.Filter := 'Sparfiler (.dat)|*.dat';
  // -------------------------------
  if OpenDialog.Execute then
  begin
    GeometryClear;
    DerobModel.Filename := OpenDialog.Filename;
    DerobModel.Open;
    pressed := True;
    SetCurrentDir('../');
    DerobModel.HouseProperties.StringValue['CaseDir'] := GetCurrentDir;
    DerobModel.HouseProperties.StringValue['StartDir'] := StartDir;
    SetCurrentDir(StartDir);
    UpdateGeometryPanel;
    mainUpdateComboBox;
    LoadClimateFiles;
    UpdatePropertiesPanel;
    UpdateEnergyPanel;
    UpdateAbsorption;
    UpdateClimatePanel;
    UpdateClimate;
    mainHide;
    Geometry.IsSelected := True;
    GeometryPanel.Visible := True;
    TreeView1.Enabled := True;
    TreeView1.HitTest := True;
    DerobModel.HouseProperties.BoolValue['GlazeChange'] := False;
  end;

end;
```

Can anyone help me out it's driving me nuts. I mean the only difference is the function LoadClimateFiles but that's called in one of the other functions instead now. The debugger says that the InitialDir is where I want it to be and that the FileName property is `''`

Comment: Why don't you set the `InitialDir` to specific directory, instead of `GetCurrentDir`? The notion of a current directory is pretty old. Better use explicit paths. -- But what is the difference between the two code blocks you show?

Comment: Current directory handling here is dubious at best. What is `SetCurrentDir('../');` meant to do?

Comment: @RudyVelthuis there's no difference between the code blocks besides that the second block is a working code from a previous version. I want to go in to `TPath.GetSharedDocumentsPath\MyApp\Cases\` Which is what `GetCurrentDir` shows. Even now when I tried ` OpenDialog.InitialDir := TPath.GetSharedDocumentsPath+'\MyApp\Cases\';` it doesn't work. This is driving my nuts.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan the `SetCurrentDir('../')` is just to go up one folder level for saving the specific folder paths which I need later on.

Comment: Why are you using process wide global state. Why don't you use absolute paths? Try setting InitialDir to `'C:\'`

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I started out using `CurrentDir` etc and just have kept with it since I didn't really know which structure I'd have on my app. `OpenDialog.InitialDir := 'C:\';` works fine, and after that I tried `OpenDialog.InitialDir :=Path.GetSharedDocumentsPath+'\MyApp\Cases\';` and now it works. Thank you but do you know why this problem occured?

Answer (score 5):

This behavior is normal. See the documentation for the [`OpenFileName.lpstrInitialDir`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646839.aspx) field:

> The initial directory. The algorithm for selecting the initial directory varies on different platforms.
>
> **Windows 7:**
>
> 1. If `lpstrInitialDir` has the same value as was passed the first time the application used an Open or Save As dialog box, the path most recently selected by the user is used as the initial directory.
> 2. Otherwise, if `lpstrFile` contains a path, that path is the initial directory.
> 3. Otherwise, if `lpstrInitialDir` is not `NULL`, it specifies the initial directory.
> 4. If `lpstrInitialDir` is `NULL` and the current directory contains any files of the specified filter types, the initial directory is the current directory.
> 5. Otherwise, the initial directory is the personal files directory of the current user.
> 6. Otherwise, the initial directory is the Desktop folder.
>
> **Windows 2000/XP/Vista:**
>
> 1. If `lpstrFile` contains a path, that path is the initial directory.
> 2. Otherwise, `lpstrInitialDir` specifies the initial directory.
> 3. Otherwise, if the application has used an Open or Save As dialog box in the past, the path most recently used is selected as the initial directory. However, if an application is not run for a long time, its saved selected path is discarded.
> 4. If `lpstrInitialDir` is `NULL` and the current directory contains any files of the specified filter types, the initial directory is the current directory.
> 5. Otherwise, the initial directory is the personal files directory of the current user.
> 6. Otherwise, the initial directory is the Desktop folder.

You've been passing the same value each time, so rule 1 applies. The OS ignores the directory your program asks for and uses the one the user prefers instead. You probably see different behavior in your older program because you've changed its behavior over time, and it no longer requests the same initial directory that it did the first time you ran the program.

You probably shouldn't worry about it.

Comment: What makes it a little bit confusing is that rule 1 applies even if the application is exited and restarted in between.

Comment: @Rob It got solved but I'd still like to know. If I'd had passed another InitialDir after `execute` would it have changed like I wanted it to?

Comment: Probably. You're the one with the code, so you can try it out yourself. If you managed to *force* the initial directory to what you want, ignoring the user's previous selection, please post your own answer here explaining it.

Comment: @RobKennedy, I probably won't mess around with this as it's driven me mad for the last couple of hours.

Comment: Is Windows 8/10 similar to Windows 7? It seems so for Win8.1 but I couldn't find a reference yet...

Comment: The page I linked tells you to use [the new API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776913.aspx#start_folder) instead, @Wolf. There, it says this: "The default folder is the folder in which the dialog starts the first time a user opens it from your application. After that, the dialog will open in the last folder a user opened or the last folder they used to save an item. See State Persistence for more details."

Answer (score 3):

How to work around that problem

If you know the correct path, then set a dummy file like

opendialog1.filename := 'C:\folder1*.doc';

That opens the right folder.
In that case, initialdir is not needed!

Comment: This works, but keep in mind that you are initialising the filename this way, which can be misleading in some circumstances.

Comment: This definitely did not work, unfortunately. Delphi 5 Professional